# Android socket connection combining sends

Tags: java, android, sockets, asyncsocket

Right now I have established a `Socket` connection with my desktop server.  In general it is working fine and I am trying to find any remaining bugs.  One that I can't solve is when I spam my "Send" button.  Sometimes it will combine messages meant to be sent separately into one message.  I'm fairly sure that this is an Android issue and not an issue with my server.  Here is an example of what happens (console output from server):

```
XX.XX.XX.XX: {"control":[],"commands":[]}
XX.XX.XX.XX: {"control":[],"commands":[]}
XX.XX.XX.XX: {"control":[],"commands":[]}
XX.XX.XX.XX: {"control":[],"commands":[]}{"control":[],"commands":[]}
```

This is causing my JSON parser to not work correctly.  I have the ability to connect to my server either through Bluetooth or Wifi, and I've noticed that the problem of the messages being combined only happens while using Wifi and not a BluetoothSocket.  Not to say that I don't think the BluetoothSocket could lag enough to combine like this, but there is a lot less traffic running there.  Is there any way to make sure that my packets won't be combined when being sent?  I've looked around the `Socket` options and didn't know what to look for.  Here's an example of how I send, pretty basic:

`mmDataOut.write(buffer);`

Where `mmDataOut` is just a `DataOutputStream` and `buffer` is a `byte[]`.

Also, I added the asyncsocket tag because my server is using them, not sure if that would affect anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you are using TCP.  This is expected behavior of TCP, and you need to upgrade your parser to support it.

You cannot safely assume that a chunk of data from the read end will include only one command, and additionally you cannot assume that you will get the entirety of a command in a single read.

Comment: I had a feeling it was due to TCP.  The parser I'm using couldn't handle it so I can manually walk the string to check for duplicate JSON messages before I parse. For now I'll just catch and the error and disregard the parse.  Thanks.

Comment: You really should re-assemble things into complete pieces.  If performance isn't a particular concern, it's easy to do by reading one character at a time until you find a terminating condition.

Comment: @Atlos: Although the parser might not be able to handle partial or combined messages (that's fine), it is still your responsibility to split up the messages into something the parser *can* handle. If you randomly discard messages because you gave the parser unparseable input, your communications will be unreliable and flaky.

Comment: @GregHewgill Yes I will definitely get around to it.  This is for an internal app and I don't see my userbase mashing my button, and if it drops a parse then they can just re-send.  It has been added to my TODO's :)